# Django Mongodb can't find objects by objects.all()

Tags: python, django, mongodb, shell

I follow the tutorials [here](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) from the beginning until (including) the part "Adding some templates." Here are my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField
from djangotoolbox.fields import EmbeddedModelField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = ListField()
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Comment'))
    
    class MongoMeta:
        db_table = 'blogs_post'
    
class Comment(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = EmbeddedModelField('Author')
    text = models.TextField()

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Some environment information: Django 1.5.11; Python 2.7.6; Databases: django_mongodb_engine; OS: Ubuntu-14.04

I tried at the django shell (with virtualenv activated) to insert comments, authors, and posts. Everything worked well. I double-checked at the mongo shell and found all the data I inserted using the django shell. Here is what I got from the mongo shell with db.blogs_post.find().pretty():

```
> db.blogs_post.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56716f162b464a2fd3f252f8"),
    "tags" : [
        "mongodb",
        "django"
    ],
    "text" : "Just wanted to drop a note",
    "title" : "Hello MongoDB",
    "comments" : [
        "Great post!",
        "Please, do more of these!"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56718f752b464a35593d7f23"),
    "text" : "People from haven also blog. This is a sample blog post from haven",
    "tags" : [
        "haven",
        "blog",
        "quant"
    ],
    "comments" : [
        {
            "text" : "This is a test comment",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2015-12-16T16:17:22.912Z"),
            "id" : ObjectId("56718e922b464a35593d7f22"),
            "author" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("56718e642b464a35593d7f21"),
                "name" : "xxxx",
                "email" : "xxxx@xxxx.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "title" : "This is a great post from haven"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("567191932b464a35593d7f24"),
    "text" : "",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "comments" : [
        {
            "text" : "This is a test comment",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2015-12-16T16:17:22.912Z"),
            "id" : ObjectId("56718e922b464a35593d7f22"),
            "author" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("56718e642b464a35593d7f21"),
                "name" : "xxx",
                "email" : "xxx@xxxx.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "title" : "I like cake"
}
```

Those are the data I inserted using the django shell. However, when I run Post.objects.all(), it returns an empty list. But Comment.objects.all() and Author.objects.all() do return what are on the database.

Any idea on how to fix it is greatly appreciated as I am considering MongoDB for a real-life financial project.

Thanks